# Re-rending using Setstate

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Re-rending using Setstate, logged twice and heads and tails counter adds +2 everytime on click rather than +1

```
 class CoinFlip extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                currFace: 'heads',
                flips: 0,
                counter: {
                    heads: 0,
                    tails: 0,
                },
            };

            this.flipCoin = this.flipCoin.bind(this);
        }

        flipCoin() {
            let num = Math.round(Math.random());
            let face = num === 0 ? 'heads' : 'tails';

            this.setState((st) => {
                const copy = { ...st };
                copy.flips++;
                copy.counter[face]++;
                copy.currFace = face;
                return copy;
            });
        }

        render() {
            return (
                <div>
                    <h1>Lets flip a coin</h1>
                    <Coin face={this.state.currFace} />
                    <p>
                        Out of {this.state.flips}, there have been {this.state.counter.heads}{' '}
                        heads and {this.state.counter.tails} tail
                    </p>

                    <button onClick={this.flipCoin}>Flip!</button>
                </div>
            );
        }
    }
```

there is 2 results of copy obj with double faces value when it is logged

2x 
console:
counter: {heads: 2, tails: 0}
currFace: "heads"
flips: 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to destructure a deep object, but the destructuring with `{ ...st }` creates only a shallow copy, i.e. the content of `counter` attribute will still come from the previous state, which is not allowed in React.

Easiest fix is to make a copy of the property `counter` as well:

```
  flipCoin() {
      let num = Math.round(Math.random());
      let face = num === 0 ? 'heads' : 'tails';

      this.setState((st) => {
          const copy = { ...st };
          copy.counter = { ...st.counter };
          copy.flips++;
          copy.counter[face]++;
          copy.currFace = face;
          return copy;
      });
  }
```

or to flatten the structure of your state.

Comment: what does it mean by shallow copy??

Comment: use your favorite search engine to search for *javascript shallow object copy* and you find better explanation and examples than I can give you here.